# Django Sum of Multiplied Values

Tags: python, django

I am trying to show the total weight of assets I have presented on a table.

Each Asset has a weight and a quantity and I can present the total weight of each asset as below:

```
def by_item_weight(self):
    """This Method gives the total value of the asset. Weight * Qnty"""
    total = self.asset_quantity * self.asset_weight
    return total
```

What I would like to do is take the total item weight of each asset (result of qnty * weight) and present the over all weight of all assets.

I have tried to make various combinations of the below to return the sum of the by_item_weight 'column':

```
Asset.objects.all().annotate(total=Sum('by_item_weight')
```

But I understand this will not work as by-item-weight is not defined in the model Asset.

I am presenting the table via a for loop as below on my assetslist.html template:

```
{% block content %}



<table class="well table table-striped text-center">
    <thead>
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th class="text-center">Asset ID:</th>
            <th class="text-center">Asset Name:</th>
            <th class="text-center">Asset Quantity:</th>
            <th class="text-center">Asset Weight / kg:</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total Weight / kg:</th>
            <th class="text-center">Asset Owner:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="text-center">
{% for asset in object_list %}
            <td>{{ asset.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ asset.asset_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ asset.asset_quantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ asset.asset_weight }}</td>
            <td>{{ asset.by_item_weight }}</td>
            <td>{{ asset.asset_owner }}</td>


        </tr>


{% endfor %}
```

I am new to Python and am having trouble finding a way to capture the value of each asset.by_item_weight which If I could capture in a list I presume I could them sum the list and show the result.

My Models

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    asset_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    asset_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    asset_owner = models.ForeignKey(
        'AssetOwner',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    ) # This should be a Foreign Key Drop down of AssetOwners owner_name.


    def by_item_weight(self):
        """This Method gives the total value of the asset. Weight * Qnty"""
        total = self.asset_quantity * self.asset_weight
        return total

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.asset_name)
        return 'Asset Quantity: {}'.format(self.asset_quantity)
        return 'Asset Weight: {}'.format(self.asset_weight)
        return 'Asset Owner: {}'.format(self.asset_owner)
        return 'Asset Owner: {}'.format(self.asset_owner)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATED:

No Errors now, but still not able to show/display the value of sum_total

New Template

```
   {% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1 class='text-center'>This is the full asset list not split by owner</h1></br>

    <table class="well table table-striped text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th class="text-center">Asset ID:</th>
                <th class="text-center">Asset Name:</th>
                <th class="text-center">Asset Quantity:</th>
                <th class="text-center">Asset Weight / kg:</th>
                <th class="text-center">Total Weight / kg:</th>
                <th class="text-center">Asset Owner:</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="text-center">
    {% for asset in object_list %}
                <td>{{ asset.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_weight }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.by_item_weight }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_owner }}</td>


            </tr>


    {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>


<p class="" style="">Total Weight In Stock : {{ asset.sum_total }}</p>


<p class="text-center">{% include "sam/includes/backtosam.html" %}</p>



{% endblock %}
```

New Models

```
 from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.db import models
    from django.db.models import Sum, F, Count
    from django.db.models import Max
    from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper
    from django.db.models import Aggregate

    class Asset(models.Model):
        asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        asset_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        asset_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        asset_owner = models.ForeignKey(
            'AssetOwner',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        ) # This should be a Foreign Key Drop down of AssetOwners owner_name.
    def by_item_weight(self):
        """This Method gives the total value of the asset. Weight * Qnty"""
        total = self.asset_quantity * self.asset_weight
        return total

    def sum_total(self):
        assets = Asset.objects.all().annotate(
        total_weight=ExpressionWrapper(F('asset_quantity') *     F('asset_weight'),output_field=IntegerField))
        the_sum = assets.aggregate(total=Sum('total_weight'))
        return the_sum

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.asset_name)
        return 'Asset Quantity: {}'.format(self.asset_quantity)
        return 'Asset Weight: {}'.format(self.asset_weight)
        return 'Asset Owner: {}'.format(self.asset_owner)
        return 'Asset Owner: {}'.format(self.asset_owner)
        return 'Total Weight of Assets: {}'.format(self.assets)
```

Updated view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.db.models import Sum, F

def get_total_weight(self):

    total_weight = cache.get('total_weight',-1)
    if total_weight == -1:
       total_weight = Asset.objects.annotate(total_weight=F('asset_quantity')*F('asset_weight')).aggregate(total=Sum('total_weight'))
       # this is tested
       cache.set('total_weight',total_weight)
       return total_weight

def index(request):

    return render(request, 'sam/index.html')

def assetslist(request):

    return render(request,'sam/assetslist.html',{'total_weight': get_total_weight}, assets = Asset.objects.all())
```

I suspect there is an issue with the above assetslist method which I am not apparently calling.

Template

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1 class='text-center'>This is the full asset list not split by owner</h1></br>

    <table class="well table table-striped text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th class="text-center">Asset ID:</th>
                <th class="text-center">Asset Name:</th>
                <th class="text-center">Asset Quantity:</th>
                <th class="text-center">Asset Weight / kg:</th>
                <th class="text-center">Total Weight / kg:</th>
                <th class="text-center">Asset Owner:</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="text-center">
    {% for asset in object_list %}
                <td>{{ asset.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_weight }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.by_item_weight }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_owner }}</td>



            </tr>


    {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>
<p class="" style="">Total Weight In Stock : {{ get_total_weight }}</p>
<p class="" style="">Total Weight In Stock : {{ assetslist }}</p>



    <!-- <table class="well table table-striped text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">

                <th class="text-center"></th>
                <th class="text-center"></th>
                <th class="text-center"></th>
                <th class="text-center"></th>
                <th class="text-center">Total Weight / kg:</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="text-center">
    {% for sum_weight in object_list %}

                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ asset.sum_total }}</td>

            </tr>


    {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table> -->






<p class="text-center">{% include "sam/includes/backtosam.html" %}</p>



{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for any input/suggestions.

Further UPDATE:

I have adjusted the view to the below:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.db.models import Sum, F


def get_total_weight(self):
    total_weight = cache.get('total_weight',-1)
    if total_weight == -1:
       total_weight = Asset.objects.annotate(total_weight=F('asset_quantity')*F('asset_weight')).aggregate(total=Sum('total_weight'))
       # this is tested
       cache.set('total_weight',total_weight)

    return total_weight

    render(request,'template_name',{'total_weight': get_total_weight, assets = Asset.objects.all() } )
```

I am getting errors on the `assets = Asset.objects.all() } )` = sign. SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I presume that render needs to be in its own function?

UPDATE:

I have updated my views and moved the def from the models.py

my views.py file is as below

```
    def total_weight(request):

    assets = Asset.objects.all().annotate(
    total_weight=ExpressionWrapper(F('asset_quantity') * F('asset_weight'), 
                                   output_field=IntegerField() ))

    return render(request, 'sam/index.html')


def sum_total(request):

    the_total = assets.aggregate(total=Sum('total_weight'))

    return render(request, 'sam/assetlist.html')

def index(request):

    return render(request, 'sam/index.html')

def by_item_weight(self):
        """This Method gives the total value of the asset. Weight * Qnty"""
        total = self.asset_quantity * self.asset_weight
        return total

    def get_total_weight(self):
        total_weight = Asset.objects.filter(by_item_weight__isnull=True).aggregate(Sum('by_item_weight'))
        Asset.objects.annotate(total_weight=F('asset_quantity')*F('asset_weight')).aggregate(total=Sum('total_weight'))


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.asset_name)
        return '{}'.format(self.total_weight)
```

assetlist.html

There is JS below that I tried to implement to resolve this issue which did not work either.

I feel like I am missing something on the assetlist.html in calling the values of the def in the views.py.

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}


{% block content %}

<h1 class='text-center'>This is the full asset list not split by owner</h1></br>




    <table id="sum_table" class="well table table-striped text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center titlerow">
                <td class="text-center">Asset ID:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Name:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Quantity:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Weight / kg:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Total Weight / kg:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Owner:</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="text-center">

    {% for asset in object_list %}
                <td><a href="/sam/assets/{{ asset.id }}">{{ asset.id }}</></td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_weight }}</td>
                <td class="rowDataSd">{{ asset.by_item_weight }}</td>
                <td><a href="/sam/owners/">{{ asset.asset_owner }}</></td>

            </tr>

    {% endfor %}



            <tr class="totalColumn">
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class="totalCol">Total: {{ asset.get_total_weight }}</td>
                <td class=""></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<p>Hope this is full ( {{ this_view }}  )?</p>

<p class="text-center">{% include "sam/includes/backtosam.html" %}</p>

<!--
<script>
       var total = 0;
$('#sum_table tr td.rowDataSd').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
});
$('#sum_table td.totalCol').text("total: " + total);
</script>
-->

{% endblock %}
```

UPDATE - 3rd July 2016

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum, F, Count
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper
from django.db.models import Aggregate

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Asset(models.Model):
    asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    asset_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    asset_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_assets_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    asset_owner = models.ForeignKey(
        'AssetOwner',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    ) # This should be a Foreign Key Drop down of AssetOwners owner_name.

    def by_item_weight(self):
        """This Method gives the total value of the asset. Weight * Qnty"""
        total = self.asset_quantity * self.asset_weight
        return total

    def total_weight(self):

        assets = Asset.objects.all().annotate(
        total_weight=ExpressionWrapper(F('asset_quantity') * F('asset_weight'), 
                                       output_field=IntegerField()))

        the_total = assets.aggregate(total=Sum('total_weight'))

        return the_total
```

template

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}


{% block content %}

<h1 class='text-center'>This is the full asset list not split by owner</h1></br>




    <table id="sum_table" class="well table table-striped text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center titlerow">
                <td class="text-center">Asset ID:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Name:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Quantity:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Weight / kg:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Total Weight / kg:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Owner:</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="text-center">

    {% for asset in object_list %}
                <td><a href="/sam/assets/{{ asset.id }}">{{ asset.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_weight }}</td>
                <td class="rowDataSd">{{ asset.by_item_weight}}</td>
                <td><a href="/sam/owners/">{{ asset.asset_owner }}</td>



            </tr>

    {% endfor %}

    {% for total in object_list %}

            <tr class="totalColumn">
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class="totalCol">Total: {{ total.total_weight }}</td>
                <td class=""></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {% endfor %}


<p class="text-center">{% include "sam/includes/backtosam.html" %}</p>



{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [ExpressionWrapper()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/) *(mostly Django 1.8+)*

```
assets = Asset.objects.all().annotate(
    total_weight=ExpressionWrapper(F('asset_quantity') * F('asset_weight'), 
                                   output_field=IntegerField() ))
```

That should give you the total weight for each object, i.e. quantity times weight.

Now, you should be able to get a sum from all the `total_weight`s.

**Edit:** Now you can use [Aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/) to get the total

```
assets.aggregate(total=Sum('total_weight'))

{'total': 1234.5678}
```

Comment: Thanks for the above. I have incorporated this into my models but am still not getting any result displaying when I view my template / table page.  I presume something like ``<p>{{ asset.sum_total }}</p>`` should give me the result assuming my method is named sum_total? Model code is ``def sum_total(self):
        assets = Asset.objects.all().annotate(
        total_weight=ExpressionWrapper(F('asset_quantity') * F('asset_weight'),output_field=IntegerField))
        return assets``

Comment: Added it to my answer

Comment: Thanks @C14L I have updated my models and template above, I don't get an error messages but no value for the new sum_totals method appears when I  `{{ asset.sum_total }}` on the template.

Comment: Just tested it, I missed the parenthesis for `IntegerField()`. Now it works, including the Sum(). The `aggregate()` call will return a `dict` with only one key: `{'total': 1234.5678}`.

Comment: I have updated the above with my most current view and relevant .htlm.

Comment: I think I am getting somewhere. Although I am getting a global name 'IntegerField' is not defined error. Updated models.py above.

Comment: Resolved,I had not imported IntegerField `from django.db.models import IntegerField` Thanks