# Sum django generated table values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have a table which is populated by a django for loop below. I have added some JavaScript to sum/add all the totals in the asset.by_item_weight column.

For some reason I am not getting the value returned in the totalCol td.

I have put the script tag at the bottom of this .html in the hope that the django generated values will be loaded into the td before the JS is run.

It might be that I have approached this is the wrong way or that this `<script>` should be else where.

I have tried to put the script tag into the personal/header.html before the closing body tag which made no difference.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

```
 {% extends "personal/header.html" %}


{% block content %}

<h1 class='text-center'>This is the full asset list not split by owner</h1></br>




    <table id="sum_table" class="well table table-striped text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center titlerow">
                <td class="text-center">Asset ID:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Name:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Quantity:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Weight / kg:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Total Weight / kg:</td>
                <td class="text-center">Asset Owner:</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="text-center">

    {% for asset in object_list %}
                <td><a href="/sam/assets/{{ asset.id }}">{{ asset.id }}</></td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset.asset_weight }}</td>
                <td class="rowDataSd">{{ asset.by_item_weight }}</td>
                <td><a href="/sam/owners/">{{ asset.asset_owner }}</></td>

            </tr>
    {% endfor %}

            <tr class="totalColumn">
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
                <td class=""></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<p class="text-center">{% include "sam/includes/backtosam.html" %}</p>



{% endblock %}
<script>
       var totals=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var $dataRows=$("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

            $dataRows.each(function() {
                $(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function(i){        
                    totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
                });
            });
            $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function(i){  
                $(this).html("total:"+totals[i]);
            });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you doing the calculation in JS at all? Why not in your view?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have tried to do the cal in the view but cant get the value to display.

Comment: @M.Rob so your solution to fix an issue you can't manage in a suitable context, is to try to fix it in an unsuitable context, though you can't manage it either? Take care about asking the right question. If you tried to do X, failed and try to do it using Y, but failed to do Y as well. Ask how to do X, not how to do Y.

Comment: Hi Antoine. I have been looking for a solution to this issue for some time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514626/django-sum-of-multiplied-values and it occurred to me that maybe I am trying to do something with django that is or not appropriate. It occurred to me that I might be able to solve this problem with some JavaScript.  I don't have the appropriate level of knowledge or experience in either language (yet) to resolve the issue in either django or JavaScript which is why I am reaching out to the wider community for advice. I do appreciate you taking the time to respond to my post

Comment: post the relevent section of your view please

Comment: @e4c5 view as as follows `def total_weight(request):
    
    assets = Asset.objects.all().annotate(
    total_weight=ExpressionWrapper(F('asset_quantity') * F('asset_weight'), 
                                   output_field=IntegerField() ))
    
    return render(request, 'sam/index.html')


def sum_total(request):
    
    the_total = assets.aggregate(total=Sum('total_weight'))
    
    return render(request, 'sam/assetlist.html')`

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks for the response, I have resolved this issue and have updated the relevant post. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Why do you iterate over `#sum_table td.totalCol` while you have only one?
- Why do you prefill your array with a bunch of zeros?
- Why do you use an array at all?

Your code should rather look like this:

```
var total = 0;
$('#sum_table tr td.rowDataSd').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
});
$('#sum_table td.totalCol').text("total: " + total);
```

- And as Daniel Roseman said, why are you doing this in JS?

Comment: Hi Antoine, why JS, desperation. I have failed to find an appropriate solution via django. I am beginning to think that what I am trying to achieve is not possible in django, which is why I have tried to solve the problem with JS. Clearly based on the reactions to this question JS is not way forward. Thanks for your response, I appreciate you taking the time to respond to my question.